# Central extension of perfect group has perfect commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

Suppose that $ G/Z(G) $ is perfect. Can we conclude that the commutator subgroup $ [G,G] $ is perfect?

I think that $ [G,G] $ must be a perfect central extension of $ G/Z(G) $ and that $ G $ has the structure of a central product of $ Z(G) $ with $ [G,G] $ over $ Z([G,G]) $
$$
G\cong Z(G) \circ_{Z([G,G])} [G,G]
$$

Also I think $ [G,G] $ is the maximal perfect subgroup of $ G $.

Comment: Yes, as I said in a comment to an earlier question, $G/Z(G)$ perfect implies that $[G,G]$ is perfect. An element of $[G,G]$ is a product of commutators $[g,h]$ with $g,h \in G$. Since $G/Z(G)$ is perfect, we have $g=g'z$ and $h=h'y$ with $g',h' \in[G,G]$ and $y,z \in Z(G)$, and then $[g,h]=[g',h']$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Would you be interested in promoting this comment to an answer?

Comment: There is no need now because Nicky Hekster has answered the question with essentially the same argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $N \unlhd G$, then $(G/N)'=G'N/N$, so if $G/Z(G)$ is non-abelian simple, it follows that $(G/Z(G))'=G'Z(G)/Z(G)=G/Z(G)$. This means that $G=G'Z(G)$ and this yields (see also the remarks of Derek Holt), $G'=G''$, so $G'$ is perfect. In addition, $Z_2(G)=Z(G)$, which I leave as an exercise to you.

Comment: As I said in my comment, this argument works whenever $G/Z(G)$ is perfect.

Comment: ah ok to reflect the broader nature of the result and the proof perhaps I should edit the original question relaxing assumption from non-abelian simple to perfect. Also what does $ Z_2(G) $ mean?

Comment: $Z_2(G)$ is the second term of the upper central series (look up the definition), $Z_2(G)/Z(G):=Z(G/Z(G))$.